# Excel: how to combine two columns with conditions

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

I have a short excel table like the following in each cell:

```
Estimate    Std. Error
-302.3000   40.6300
0.7594      0.1067
0.3180      0.0771
-0.7590     0.0689
-1.5620     0.0774
0.4388      0.0541
-0.3687     0.0619 
0.0229      0.0588
0.0002      0.0000
0.0000      0.0000
```

and I want to insert the second column value right beneath each of the value in the first column. Ideally, I want a result like the following:

```
-302.3000   
(40.6300)
0.7594
(0.1067)        
0.3180
(0.0771)        
-0.7590     
(0.0689)
```

I know this can be done manually, but I have seven tables like this. So I am looking for some more efficient way in excel. Would greatly appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will do it:

```
=INDEX($A:$B,(ROW(1:1)-1)/2+2,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,2)+1)
```

Put it in the first cell you want and drag down.

[image]

To put the `()` around every second number use add and IF() before and after:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,2),"(","") & INDEX($A:$B,(ROW(1:1)-1)/2+2,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,2)+1) & IF(MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,2),")","")
```

[image]